# Hyperlink not clickable on Internet Explorer if use Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, href, actionlink

I used the mvc actionlink to get the url. It is working fine in chrome. But in IE it is not even clicking. i used the following code to navigate the page.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetHelpDocuments", "Document")">
            <span class="navsprite helplink"></span>
            <span>Help</span>
```

I don't find any error in my above code. But please give alternate solution for this.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Relevant here is the HTML that is generated and the CSS that is applied to it, as well as any JavaScript that is running on the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696793/asp-net-mvc-razor-url-action-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-8 - please look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I used localtion.href to get the actual location href

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetHelpDocuments", "Document")" onclick='location.href = this.getAttribute("href")'> 
           <span class="navsprite helplink" ></span>
            <span>Help</span>
```